# How can I send property which added to collection to blade in livewire component?

Tags: laravel-livewire

When I add a property to my eloquent collection and want to read it on blade give me this error:

> Property [totalPrice] does not exist

**Basket Component:**

```
class Basket extends Component
{

use AuthorizesRequests;

public $basket;


public function mount()
{
    if(Auth::user()){
    $basket= auth()->user()->cart;

    $this->basket=$basket;

    $this->basket->totalPrice=10; //In this line i add totalPrice to basket collection and set it to 10

    }

 }

public function render()
 {
    return view('livewire.basket');
 }
}
```

Piece of my code I write in `livewire.basket.blade`:

```
<span class="float-left" id="basketPrice">{{$basket->totalPrice}}</span>
```

Comment: Have you considered that `Auth::user()` might be failing? Might be worthwhile doing a `dd(Auth::user())` to confirm it has a value you expect.

Comment: It has . when I do `$this->basket->totalPrice=10;`  actually the totalPrice property add to basket.

Comment: Well at some point it must be failing as `if(Auth::user())` is the only thing preventing `totalPrice` being set on the `$basket`. Unless you have omitted other code?

Comment: make dd to basket on assign dd(auth()->user()->cart)...did you get a model or a collection?

Comment: if i do dd($this->basket->totalPrice) before `return view('livewire.basket');` it show me 10 but in blade i cant access to it.

Comment: Does your `Cart` model have the property `totalPrice`?

Comment: No. but I think `$this->basket->totalPrice=10`  add `totalPrice` property to `basket` field of `Basket` component. and when I `dd($this->basket)` it has property `totalPrice` but in blade it can not access to it

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this and how to fix it? I’m having the same issue. Any collection containing custom properties and stored in the Livewire component _lose_ their custom properties when passed to the Blade view.